Unable to start debug or download with OpenOCD Clion
I am trying to download a stm32 program on clion. It compiles right but when I run download or debug, I got a problem. I can use keil to download it right.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results mi
ght differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 10000 kHz
Info : clock speed 10000 kHz
[0mInfo : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.206324
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] Cortex-M3 r1p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32f1x.cpu] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : gdb port disabled
[stm32f1x.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x200001e0 msp: 0x20005000
** Programming Started **
Info : device id = 0x00004010
Warn : Cannot identify target as a STM32 family.
Error: auto_probe failed
embedded:startup.tcl:1467: Error: ** Programming Failed **
in procedure 'program'
in procedure 'program_error' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 1532
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 1467

My cfg(I use stlink v2 which looks like a USB)
# choose st-link/j-link/dap-link etc.
#adapter driver cmsis-dap
#transport select swd
source [find interface/stlink.cfg]
transport select hla_swd
source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]
# download speed = 10MHz
adapter speed 10000

English is not my native language, so please forgive some of my faults on gramma and vocabulary, thanks!
I'm new to embedded development so please tell me anything if any information could be helpful. Thanks!
I have searched for several hours for :

auto_probe failed
Cannot identify target as a STM32 family
'program_error' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl"

I have turned on serial debug on stm32cubemx.
My chip is stm32F103C8T6 and its id code starting with 01x.
